# Restore user in DataBase that in master have mapped the child database but in child database doesn't have the user created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions, restore, users

I don't know why te following database arrive to this point but this is the situation

In master security you can see the defcon\axadmin user with DAXTest database mapped

But if you go to the database secury the user AXAdmin doesn't exist.

I can't edit any information about mapping of AXadmin user because throw the following error:

Also I can't delete this user in master because when I create again have the same mapping.

And if you check with te following sql:

```
use master
go
select * from syslogins where name='DEFCON\axadmin'
go 

use daxtest
go
select * from sysusers where name='DEFCON\axadmin'
go
```

You can see the user in master database but doesn't exist in DAXTest

I try to create in DAXTest

```
CREATE USER [defcon\axadmin] FOR LOGIN [defcon\axadmin];
```

The user have another session start name

But if I try to edit

```
ALTER USER [DEFCON\axadmin] WITH LOGIN=[DEFCON\axadmin]
```

You can't edit the user because doesn't exist

Error:

Comment: Check that you aren't running a case sensitive collation that would impact your queries for checking. Also, worth checking to see if it shows up `SELECT dp.name AS DBUser, sp.name AS LoginName FROM sys.database_principals dp JOIN sys.server_principals sp ON dp.sid = sp.sid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login `DEFCON\axadmin` is `sysadmin` on the current server.

This means that it cannot be mapped to any database as `DEFCON\axadmin` user, **it's already mapped** and it's mapped as `dbo` in any database.

To see this just impersonate this login and ask for a user in that database:

```
use DAXTest;
execute as login = 'DEFCON\axadmin';
select user;
-- you'll see 'dbo' here
select select IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin');
-- you'll get 1 here
revert;
```

Comment: yes you are on the right, but what I have to do to solve my problem? I only can use AxAdmin

Comment: What is your problem? This login already has all possible permissions, you should not map it or give any permission, he has no access problem

Comment: yes, you make me see that isn't a access problem

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are restoring a database on a server that is different from the server that the original backup was made on. If this is the case, then there will be a ghost login for all of the security accounts that were on the database on the original server. Try the following:

```
USE [DAXTEST]
EXEC sp_dropuser 'DEFCON\axadmin'
GO

USE [DAXTEST]
create user [DEFCON\axadmin] from login [DEFCON\axadmin]
GO

USE [DAXTEST]
exec sp_addrolemember 'db_owner',[DEFCON\axadmin]
GO
```